# Using different controls in a editable column

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoGrid initialized in cshtml. It use ajax binding.
The grid model looks like 
int id,
int typeId,
string name.
string value.

The grid has 2 columns Name and Value and value is editable InCell.
For now grid works well with using by default usual textbox as editor.
I have to improve the grid to have possibility of using different controls in the "value" field depending of the value of "typeId".
I tried to use custom EditorTemplate for that but I cannot find a way to pass typeId to the template (the column is bound to "value").
Is it possible to pass there an extra parameter from the grid model or reach it somehow from the template?

Regards, Alexey

Comment: You can do it by using the Edit event of grid and prevent editing according to the value of typeId. Could you please provide some code in order to give you an answer? The code for the grid for example in order to wright the correct javascript function for the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the way with preventing editing is not that I want. I know how to do that way. But I would like to use templating for that.